# Update all map values in DynamoDB using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have the following table in DynamoDB

```
id: int
options: map
    some_option: 0
    some_other_option: 0
```

I want to update all the values of the options map. Here is what I have tried, but I can't seem to find how to select all of the keys in the options map and update their values.

```
response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': my_id,
    }, 
    UpdateExpression='SET options.#s = 10',  
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        "#s": *
    },  
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

Comment: Do you know the keys that are in every map in advance? If not, you probably have to get each item and build an update expression for the keys present. Collect a number of items together and then issue a batch write.